# Using Xpath, How to Get value from style tag

Tags: xpath

I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="runtime-content" style="margin:12px;">
    <style type="text/css" scoped="scoped">
      .theme-entry .tab-box .tab-box-body { background-image:url('/Runtime/Image.ashx?ImID=38'); background-repeat:repeat-y; background-size:auto; background-position:center left; }
      .theme-entry .runtime-form { width:100%; }
      .theme-entry .form { padding:12px; background-image:url('/Runtime/Image.ashx?ImID=38'); background-repeat:repeat-y; background-size:auto; background-position:center left; }
      .form .row > .view > *,  .form .row > .formcontrol > * { margin:0px 6px; }
      html[dir=ltr] .form .row > *:first-child > * { margin-left:0px; }
      html[dir=rtl] .form .row > *:first-child > * { margin-right:0px; }
```

I am trying to check if the value from the `background-image` is the same that I have that is stored somewhere else.

So I've tried a few things such as:

1. `//div[@class='runtime-content'] //*[text()[contains(.,'/Runtime/Image.ashx?ImID=38')]]`
2. `//*[text()[contains(., '/Runtime/Image.ashx?ImID=38')]]`

They produce the following:

[image]

I have noticed there is a outer/Inner HTML/Text that has the data:

[image]

I usualy used something like this:

```
`//div[@class='MyForm-Forms-Controls-Web-Table Grid-Layout'][contains(@style,'background-repeat:repeat')]`
```

and that worked for me but the difference was that the data was in the tag itself:

```
<div id="688cf704a82b_Table" name="Table" class="MyForm-Forms-Controls-Web-Table Grid-Layout" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;grid-template-rows:auto auto auto ;width:;background-image:url(/Runtime/Image.ashx?ImID=35);background-color:transparent;grid-template-columns.......
```

Is there a way to get that inner/outerHTML/Text of some other way to get the data?

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting basicaly a True/False. I have a program I created that will evalutae this. Using `//div[@class='MyForm-Forms-Controls-Web-Table Grid-Layout'][contains(@style,'background-repeat:repeat')]` in chrome console using `$x("xxx")` brought back data anf If I click on data it would point to the exact attrabute. So in an assert I could assert if the image id I expect and the one in the code is the same. Hope this make sense.

Comment: I understand, but my question is - what is the image id you use in the assertion?

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this to select the element which contains the url :

```
//div[@class='runtime-content']/style[contains(.,'background-image:url')]/text()
```

You can output the value with the following XPath :

```
substring-after(substring-before(//div[@class="runtime-content"]/style[contains(.,"background-image:url")],"'); background-repeat"),"-image:url('")
```

Output :  `/Runtime/Image.ashx?ImID=38`

To return `True` or `False` with `Python` and `LXML` (we store and compare the value of background) :

```
data = """<div class="runtime-content" style="margin:12px;">
    <style type="text/css" scoped="scoped">
      .theme-entry .tab-box .tab-box-body { background-image:url('/Runtime/Image.ashx?ImID=38'); background-repeat:repeat-y; background-size:auto; background-position:center left; }
      .theme-entry .runtime-form { width:100%; }
      .theme-entry .form { padding:12px; background-image:url('/Runtime/Image.ashx?ImID=38'); background-repeat:repeat-y; background-size:auto; background-position:center left; }
      .form .row > .view > *,  .form .row > .formcontrol > * { margin:0px 6px; }
      html[dir=ltr] .form .row > *:first-child > * { margin-left:0px; }
      html[dir=rtl] .form .row > *:first-child > * { margin-right:0px; }</style>
      </div>"""

import lxml.html
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
background = "/Runtime/Image.ashx?ImID=38"
print(tree.xpath('substring-after(substring-before(//div[@class="runtime-content"]/style[contains(.,"background-image:url")],"\'); background-repeat"),"-image:url(\'")="{}"'.format(background)))
```

Output : `True`